# Playing sound through bluetooth earphones (20.04, Jabra Elite 65t)

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I'm not sure how to add much more helpful info beyond the subject.

This has not always been the case - a few weeks ago I was able to pair my earphones to the laptop and have sound come out of them. However now it seems to no longer work. I don't know what logs to check - the settings page lets me choose the earphones, and then when I play sound it totally ignores the setting and sound just comes out of the laptop speakers instead.

Unpair and re-pair doesn't seem to work; turning bluetooth off and on doesn't seem to work. The earphones work fine with my phone or tablet, and the laptop plays fine through wired headphones. Changing between high fidelity and headset head unit makes a noise in the headphones but doesn't change the fact that sound only comes out of the speakers.

[image: Screenshot of sound settings]

Comment: Sometimes toggling between output devices works. Try setting it to internal audio and then back to headphones/headset even if the latter was selected already.

Comment: I have the same problem with the same headset with one computer but not with the second computer.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks, yes I have done some toggling but it hasn't had an effect. Previously rebooting seemed to work but I am at a point where none of those little hacks seem to affect it